# Como actualizo un campo depende del id

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito actualizar un campo de la base de datos seleccionando el id que le mande a través de la url.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-notes'])) {

    require "./config.php";

    $id_send = $_POST['id_send'];

    $notes = $_POST['notes'];

    $sql = "UPDATE examenes SET notas= '$notes' WHERE id = '$id_send' ";

}
```

Y luego hago el update a la base de datos seleccionando el id que recibí anteriormente, pero no se actualiza

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Prueba sin el `if`.

Comment: Agrega el formulario a la pregunta. No sabemos lo que son esos $_POST ni como los estas enviando.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @masterguru deberías añadir el formulario por si acaso :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claramente te falta la ejecución del `UPDATE` con una instrucción del tipo `$conn->query($sql);`, previa conexión a la base de datos, que entiendo hayas hecho en `config.php`.

Es decir:

```
$conn = mysqli('localhost','root','','base_datos_cole');
$conn->query($sql);
```

Y, para evitar inyecciones de código a través de tu formulario, mejor utiliza una consulta preparada:

```
$conn = mysqli('localhost','root','','base_datos_cole');
$rs = $conn->prepare("
  UPDATE examenes SET notas = ? WHERE id = ?;
");
$rs->bind_param('si',$_POST['notes'],$_POST['id_send']);
$rs->execute();
$rs->close();
```

Bueno, y tal vez asegurarte de que formulario envíe algo en `$_POST['btn-notes']`.